# Google App Engine parsing website locally and online

Tags: google-app-engine, parsing, localhost, behavior

I'm using Google App Engine with Python and I want to parse this [website](http://adriahf.comuv.com/dades_reals_REE/dadesReals) and get the displayed data, that changes over time. The problem is: the application works perfect when I'm running it locally but it doesn't (displays the same old information) when it's running online. I'm using a library called urllib and I don't get any error, just the same old data. I can't figure out what's happening so I would appreciate some ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because App Engine caches http requests.

I am not familiar with **urllib**, but with **urlfetch** from **google.appengine.api** to ensure you are getting the content fresh from the website you need to set the **Cache-Control** header, in the example below it will only return a cached page if it is less than 30 seconds old, otherwise it will go to the website to get the page fresh.

```
content = urlfetch.fetch(url, headers = {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=30'})
```